# Memory card game click event not working on mobile properly but works perfectly fine on computer

Tags: javascript, css

I was working on a free code camp memory card challenge and for some reason only on mobile when I click the front of the card it will flip but show the front of the card again although it should be the back showing. Everything works perfectly fine on my computer with chrome. It is only when switching to a mobile phone that this problem occurs whether it be chrome, safari or firefox.. can someone help me figure this? out I would greatly appreciate the help I am not quite sure how to fix this issue.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;
  isMatch ? disableCards(): unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  const mySound0 = document.getElementById("sound");
  mySound0.play();
  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
const mySound1 = document.getElementById("soundWrong");
    mySound1.play();
    resetBoard();
  }, 1500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0; 
text-decoration:none;
border:none;
box-sizing:border-box;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.grid{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr;
grid-template-rows:100vh;
}
.background-image{ 
background-size:cover;
background-image: url("https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert.jpg");
background-position:bottom;
display:grid;
}
.gradient-overlay{
background:#fbb99ac4;
display:flex; 
}
.background-image,.gradient-overlay{
grid-column:1;
grid-row:1;
}
.front-face,.back-face{
  border-radius:5px;
  padding: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front-face{
 transform:rotateY(180deg); 
  height: auto;
}
.back-face{
  background-color: #f6938a;
  
}
.memory-card{
  border-radius:5px;
 margin:5px; 
 width:calc(25% - 10px);
 height:calc(33.333% - 10px);
  position:relative;
  transform:scale(1);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transition:transform .5s;
    background-color:#a1b2a1;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.memory-card:active{
 transform:scale(.97); 
 transition:transform .2s;
}
.memory-card.flip{
 transform:rotateY(180deg); 
}
.memory-game{
  width:640px;
  height:640px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin:auto;
  perspective:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="background-image"></div>  
  <div class="gradient-overlay">
    <div class="memory-game">
    <div class="memory-card" data-framework="1">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/cactus0.png"alt="1-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="1-back">
    </div>
     <div class="memory-card" data-framework="1">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/cactus0.png"alt="1-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="1-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="2">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/cloud0.png"alt="2-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="2-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="2">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/cloud0.png"alt="2-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="2-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="3">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/hat0.png"alt="3-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="3-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="3">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/hat0.png"alt="3-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="3-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="4">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/sand0.png"alt="4-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="4-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="4">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/sand0.png"alt="4-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="4-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="5">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/smoke0.png"alt="5-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="5-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="5">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/smoke0.png"alt="5-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="5-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="6">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/sun0.png"alt="6-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="6-back">
    </div>
        <div class="memory-card" data-framework="6">
      <img class="front-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/sun0.png"alt="6-front">
      <img class="back-face" src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/desert90deg.jpg"alt="6-back">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <audio id="sound">
  <source src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/154887__unfa__beep-good.ogg" />
</audio>
  <audio id="soundWrong">
  <source src="https://assets.codepen.io/1179484/131657__bertrof__game-sound-wrong.wav" />
</audio>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem you encounter ? I get this error when I am finding 2 match cards 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: confetti is not defined`, is this what you mean ?

Comment: when I click on the card to flip to the other side it flips but then shows the back of the card again and not the actual photo that is on the other side .

Comment: no not about that it is defined in my codepen ill take it off here but this is not the issue.

Comment: you are using arrow functions in your code and this js feature is not valid in all browsers 
try using `function (x) {}` instead of arrow functions

Comment: You have provided far too much code and not enough clarity about the specific problem you are observing. If you think it is a CSS issue then your first step should be to try and recreate the issue using the minimal amount of CSS code.